# Adding elements to list in python in proper order

Tags: python

I want to add element to list using specific index. Using insert it is not working for me as it should in all cases. Please take a look:

```
rest = [666, 555, 222]
s= sorted(rest)

list1 = []    
list1.insert(rest.index(s[0]),3)
list1.insert(rest.index(s[1]),2)
list1.insert(rest.index(s[2]),1)

print list1
```

So what I wanted to achieve - highest value mapped to lowest from rest list.
But what I get is:
1, 3, 2 and the goal is to be 1, 2, 3 (in this case).

I understand that that is how insert function works, but is there any other way to acheive what I want?

Comment: I have answered your question. If that helps, accept the answer or comment to highlight your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
rest = [666, 555, 222]
s= sorted(rest)

list1 = [0] * len(rest)    
list1[rest.index(s[0])] = 3
list1[rest.index(s[1])] = 2
list1[rest.index(s[2])] = 1

print list1
```

The above code gives `[1, 2, 3]` as output (as you expect).

Comment: Thanks Wasi, that's it.

Comment: @Irt best way to thank is through accepting the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to permanently sort the list you can write:

```
list1.sort()
```

This will sort the list from smallest to biggest.

Comment: This is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: Sorry, what does OP mean?

Comment: OP = Original Poster. a.k.a the one who made the question